# Complexity of NP classes

Tags: algorithm

Since P problems are problems whereby the algorithms needed to solve them can be done in polynomial or less time, is it fair to say that NP problems are problems whereby there does not exist a polynomial algorithm to solve it?

Basically, are all problems that require an algorithm complexity of more than polynomial considered to be NP?

And so does P=NP basically says, "is there a way to solve problems that all along have been solved using algorithms that take longer than polynomial time, but this time solving them in polynomial time?"

Comment: This is way too informal and as you state it, wrong, as every problem in P is also in NP. Go by the [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem).

Comment: You seem to be looking for **NP-hard**, not NP (because, as sascha pointed out, NP includes P - the P=NP problem wouldn't make much sense if it didn't). ["If P ≠ NP, then NP-hard problems cannot be solved in polynomial time."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness).

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect.  For a proper definition, use google.  For a brief explanation:

NP doesn't stand for "not polynomial time" it stands for "non-deterministic polynomial time".  Roughly, what that means is that a solution can be verified in polynomial time, although it may not be possible to find a solution in polynomial time.  An example is graph coloring.  If you are given a graph and a coloring, it is easy to verify whether the coloring is proper in polynomial time (i.e. look at each edge and see if the colors are different).  But, if P != NP, then it is impossible to find a coloring in polynomial time, or to determine whether a coloring exists, because graph coloring is NP-hard.

So `P=NP` would mean (again, roughly and informally) that any problem for which a solution can be verified in polynomial time, a solution can also be found in polynomial time.

NOTE: like I said, this is a brief and informal explanation.  Technically P and NP only apply to decision problems, so only problems with a yes/no answer can belong to either class (e.g. determining whether a coloring exists is a problem in NP, but finding a coloring is not, because it is not a decision problem).

Comment: Thank you for clearing my doubt, it really helped a lot. 

What about problems that run in P time, but does not have a way of verifying whether the solution is complete? For example Insertion Sort would continue to run until the end of the array, it doesn't decide when to stop. Would Insertion Sort be still part of P, and thus be part of NP as well?